# Why add_action hook don`t execute js code

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Trying to connect to a plug-in action to set a variable in localstorage after a specific action.

The code looks like this

```
do_action( 'some_action', $insert_id )

add_action('some_action', 'func', 10, 1);

function func($id) 
{?
<script>
    localStorage.setItem('is_item', 1 );
</script>
<?php}
```

My code is not fired but simply added to the code in this way sceen from console 
[image]

Comment: where did you added `do_action( 'some_action', $insert_id )`? I mean in which file?

Comment: Of course I added to function.php

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, You need to add the `do_action` function where you want this function to apply. In your case, it should be an HTML document. For example:

**function.php**

```
add_action('some_action', 'func', 10, 1);
function func($id) 
{
?>
   <script>
       localStorage.setItem('is_item', 1 );
   </script>
<?php
}
```

in **header.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php do_action( 'some_action', $insert_id )  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but do_action calls the plugin in its files. I'm just plugging into this action with my action. Here is the plugin file https://github.com/arshidkv12/contact-form-cfdb7/blob/master/contact-form-cfdb-7.php  line 146 – Rasty Rayan 5 secs ago

Comment: Actions do NOT have to be in the same file to apply. The way you do it is applying it in functions.php which applies before the template loads and that's way it does not work.

Comment: Now is ok. Thank you. I added do_action to the footer and it's ok ;-)